# SHA 256 Encryption using edtftpj-pro-4.6.2

Tags: sftp, sha256, edtftpj

Can you please indicate how can I enable SHA 256 encryption during SFTP connectivity. Currently I am using below code to connect to SFTP. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
        SSHFTPClient ftp = new SSHFTPClient();
        ftp.setRemoteHost("hostname");
        ftp.setRemotePort(23);
        ftp.setAuthentication("username", "password");
        ftp.getValidator().setHostValidationEnabled(false);
        ftp.connect();
```

Comment: SHA-256 is not an encryption

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ftp.setAlgorithmEnabled(SSHFTPAlgorithm.MAC_SHA2_256, true);
```

See [here](https://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpjssl/examples/howto/use_binary_ascii_mode/UseTransferModes.java.html) for an example.